# Trying to use Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Not sure how to describe this error, but I'll try. I'm trying to learn to use the Play Framework for a project I'm collaborating on, and a few hours into but having trouble.

After creating a new project with activator, entering the directory and then typing activator, I then type "play" and get this output:

```
➜  ix  activator
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ace/Projects/ix/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/ace/Projects/ix/project/}ix-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to ix (in build file:/Users/ace/Projects/ix/)
[ix] $ play
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: apply, last, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: play
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: play (similar: playStop, playConf, play-stop)
[error] play
[error]
```

I can't make any sense of it. Literally just installed everything today (Scala/Play Framework) and using it on OSX 10.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the "activator" command instead of "play". This has been the case since [version 2.3](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23):

> The first thing you’ll notice about Play 2.3 is that the play command
>   has become the activator command. Play has been updated to use
>   Activator...

Comment: So then I've probably been following outdated documentation? Eh, just my luck. So then when I see documentation that starts with "play", what they are really saying is "activator"?

Comment: Just checked and yep - outdated docs. Love it when that happens. :) Thanks for pointing this out Atif!

Comment: If you want to be a real go-getter, you can submit a pull request for the docs since they are on github. :)